# Instantiate a UIViewController with an embedded UITabBarController

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller

I have a ViewController and that VC has an embedded TabBarController.

With my code, the ViewController is presented without the TabBar. How can I also instantiate the TabBarController?

```
    let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainViewController") as! MainViewController
    nextViewController.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
    nextViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
    if let coordinates = locationManager.location?.coordinate {
        nextViewController.coordinates = coordinates
    }
    nextViewController.posts = posts
    self.present(nextViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: How exactly is that TabBarController "embedded" in MainViewController?

Comment: Storyboard - Editor - Embed in ..

Comment: So... to me it sounds like it's actually the other way round and your MainViewController is embedded in your TabBarController. In that case don't present the MainViewController, but present the TabBarController that contains it.

Comment: That was also my first idea, but the problem is that I am passing data to my MainViewController. How can I pass the data if I present the TabBarVC?

Comment: That is a somewhat different question and depends very much on your architectural choices :)
But to try something quick & dirty: in general you can access any UITabBarController's view controllers via its `.viewControllers` property.